# PHP Super simple super light template engine to create a menu

Tags: php, template-engine

I am trying to make a super lightweight templating engine that can do ALMOST nothing.
Why another templating engine? Because we have sooo many that can do or just NOTHING or too much..

What I DON'T want to do is using all variables given and compile PHP code.
What I DON'T want to do is creating a simple script that does just str_replace and period...
However I also don't want any PHP code or lookalikes inside my template code.

What I DO want to do is loading an array and using it for creating a multi layered menu.

For example I got the following code :

```
{menu}
<ul>
{item}<li>
        <a href="[@url]">[@link]</a>
        {submenu}
        <u>
            {item_active}<li><a href="[@url]"><strong>[@link]</strong></a></li>{/item_active}
            {item}<li><a href="[@url]">[@link]</a></li>{/item}
        </ul>
        {/submenu}
    </li>
{/item}
{itemactive}<li>
        <a href="[@url]"><strong>[@link]</strong></a>
        {submenu}
        <u>
            {item_active}<li><a href="[@url]"><strong>[@link]</strong></a></li>{/item_active}
            {item}<li><a href="[@url]">[@link]</a></li>{/item}
        </ul>
        {/submenu}
    </li>{/itemactive}}
    </ul>
{/menu}
```

I want to extract the data and combining it into an array so I can use it into a menu.

After this code has been loaded I wanted to use it by calling it in my template engine by something like:

```
$tpl->block(
            'menu',
                array(
                        array(
                                'name'  =>  'item',
                                'url'   =>  'www.bing.com',
                                'link'  =>  'Bing search',
                            ),
                        array(
                                'name'  =>  'itemactive',
                                'url'   =>  'maps.bing.com',
                                'link'  =>  'Bing maps',
                            ),
                        array(
                                'name'  =>  'item',
                                'url'   =>  'www.google.com',
                                'link'  =>  'Google search',
                            ),
                        array(
                                'name'  =>  'item',
                                'url'   =>  'maps.google.com',
                                'link'  =>  'Bing maps',
                            )
                    )
            );
```

But I literally got stuck building it.
I have absolutely **0** clue how to advance... I keep rewriting code and bending the idea. But I simply cannot work out the logic to make it work.

Has anyone did something like this before? And would anyone know which logic I should use to make this work?

It doesn't have to be based upon my idea here. As long as it will work I am really happy!!

Thanks in advance!!

I already created the following code to extract the HTML

```
    ///########-------------------------------------------------------------
///########-------------------------------------------------------------
///######## FUNCTION TO FILTER A TEMPLATE FOR ARRAY BLOCKS
///########-------------------------------------------------------------
///########-------------------------------------------------------------
private function GetMultipleBlocks($var, $FileString) {

    ///########==================================================
    ///######## COMPILE THE SEARCH PATTERN
    ///########==================================================
    $StartElement   = $this->Seperators['grpstart'].$var.$this->Seperators['grpend'];
    $EndElement     = $this->Seperators['grpstart'].'\/'.$var.$this->Seperators['grpend'];

    ///######## CREATE THE SEARCHPATTERN
    $SearchPattern  = '/\\'.$StartElement.'.*?'.$EndElement.'/s';
    ///########==================================================



    ///########==================================================
    ///######## SEARCH FOR THE TEMPLATE OBJECT
    ///########==================================================
    preg_match_all($SearchPattern, $FileString, $SearchResult, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    ///########==================================================



    ///########==================================================
    ///######## IF THE FIRST PART SUBSECTION HAS BEEN SET
    ///########==================================================
    if(isset($SearchResult[0][0]) === true){
        ///######## SET THE HTML BLOCK
        $HTMLBlock = $SearchResult[0][0];

        ///########==================================================
        ///######## RESET THE START AND END ELEMENT
        ///########==================================================
        $StartElement   = $this->Seperators['grpstart'].$var.$this->Seperators['grpend'];
        $EndElement     = $this->Seperators['grpstart'].'/'.$var.$this->Seperators['grpend'];
        ///########==================================================



        ///########==================================================
        ///######## CLEANING THE TEMPLATE
        ///########==================================================
        $FileString     = str_replace($HTMLBlock, NULL, $FileString);
        ///######## CLEAN THE TEMPLATE BLOCK
        $HTMLBlock      = str_replace(array($StartElement, $EndElement), NULL, $HTMLBlock);
        ///########==================================================



        ///########==================================================
        ///######## RETURNING THE PLACEHOLDER CONTENTS
        ///########==================================================
        return($HTMLBlock);
        ///########==================================================
    }
    ///########==================================================



    ///########==================================================
    ///######## IF THE SUBSECTION HAS NOT BEEN SET
    ///########==================================================
    else{
        ///########==================================================
        ///######## RETURN FALSE
        ///########==================================================
        return(false);
        ///########==================================================
    }
    ///########==================================================
}
```

Seperators in the class defined:

```
    /// **** SEPERATORS
public      $Seperators                 =   array(
                                                    'grpstart'      =>      '{',
                                                    'grpend'        =>      '}',
                                                    'plcstart'      =>      '[@',
                                                    'plcend'        =>      ']' 
                                                );
```

Comment: This seems like way more trouble than just installing a proper template engine like Twig and ignoring the parts you don't need.

Comment: The very problem is. That when using those bloated template engines and just use the functionality that you need. You simply do not know how they work when you have an issue.

When everything works like a charm.. Then superb solution! But when even the smallest detail goes wrong. You are often in deep trouble.

Comment: You say "bloated", I say "well tested, well thought out, and community supported". They typically **do** work, as they're frequently developed by hundreds of people and used on hundreds of thousands of different websites. "But I literally got stuck building it." and your proposed syntax and sample code indicate to me you'd be better off with one of the mature, stable systems already out there. Did you try Twig? What issues did you have with it?

Comment: @ceejayoz tested and bloated are two different things.
I want to be sure that whenever I build something that I know the code from A to Z. Because I am responsible for it. You can never do this with this kind of classes. It would be worth it if I would have many requirements. But I simply want to add some basic logic and that's it. I want to add one understandable file. And not a hundred files just for templating.

Comment: Do whatever you like. Just remember that in many cases someone else may take over your code someday and curse your name.